# Deleting child node from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have the below JSON. I have to delete children node alone from the array and the remaining content should be available.

```
{
"model_type_name": "portfolio",
"hier_model_type_name": "portfolio",
"object_type": "product",
"gen_new_flag": "n",
"mkt_map_req_flag": "n",
"rule_based_flag": null,
"custom_price_type": null,
"hier_id": 468299069,
"hier_name": "AMS",
"parent_hier_id": 1,
"parent_hier_name": "Portfolio",
"level": "2",
"isLeaf": "0",
"parentage": "\\Portfolio\\AMS",
"hier_gen_new_flag": "y",
"hier_child_gen_new_flag": "y",
"hier_entity_role": "parent",
"hier_child_entity": "portfolio",
"hier_rel_type_name": "portfolio hierarchy",
"hist_flag": "y",
"hier_hist_flag": "y",
"rls_type": null,
"mass_updt_flag": null,
"children": [
    {
        "model_type_name": "dummy",
        "hier_model_type_name": "portfolio",
        "object_type": "product",
        "gen_new_flag": "n",
        "mkt_map_req_flag": "n",
        "rule_based_flag": null,
        "custom_price_type": null,
        "hier_id": 469444670,
        "hier_name": "Integrated Solutions",
        "parent_hier_id": 468299069,
        "parent_hier_name": "AMS",
        "level": "3",
        "isLeaf": "0",
        "parentage": "\\Portfolio\\AMS\\Integrated Solutions",
        "hier_gen_new_flag": "y",
        "hier_child_gen_new_flag": "y",
        "hier_entity_role": "parent",
        "hier_child_entity": "portfolio",
        "hier_rel_type_name": "portfolio hierarchy",
        "hist_flag": "y",
        "hier_hist_flag": "y",
        "rls_type": null,
        "mass_updt_flag": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "model_type_name": "dummy",
                "hier_model_type_name": "portfolio",
                "object_type": "product",
                "gen_new_flag": "n",
                "mkt_map_req_flag": "n",
                "rule_based_flag": null,
                "custom_price_type": null,
                "hier_id": 469444678,
                "hier_name": "Healthcare",
                "parent_hier_id": 469444670,
                "parent_hier_name": "Integrated Solutions",
                "level": "4",
                "isLeaf": "1",
                "parentage": "\\Portfolio\\AMS\\Integrated Solutions\\Healthcare",
                "hier_gen_new_flag": "y",
                "hier_child_gen_new_flag": "n",
                "hier_entity_role": "parent",
                "hier_child_entity": "portfolio",
                "hier_rel_type_name": "portfolio hierarchy",
                "hist_flag": "y",
                "hier_hist_flag": "y",
                "rls_type": null,
                "mass_updt_flag": null,
                "children": null,
                "hierGenNewFlag": true,
                "releaseDriven": false,
                "genNewFlag": false,
                "hierChildGenNewFlag": false,
                "massUpdateFlag": false
            }
        ],
        "hierGenNewFlag": true,
        "releaseDriven": false,
        "genNewFlag": false,
        "hierChildGenNewFlag": true,
        "massUpdateFlag": false
    }
],
"hierGenNewFlag": true,
"releaseDriven": false,
"genNewFlag": false,
"hierChildGenNewFlag": true,
"massUpdateFlag": false
```

}

I tried this code: But it is not working.. Please help

```
for(var i=0; i< $scope.selectedNode.length; i++){
                        var obj = scope.selectedNode[i];
                        for(var k in obj){
                            if(k == "children"){
                                 if(!obj[k]){
                                     delete $scope.selectedNode.children;
                                 }
                             }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: JSON is a data format for strings, you can't delete nodes in strings. Did you mean a **javascript object** ?

Comment: `if(!obj[k]){` - I think you need to check the opposite condition: _if node exists then delete it_

Comment: Yes, It is an object.. Please share your information how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because of this line:

```
if(!obj[k]){
```

The `children` will be deleted only if the value is `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `NaN` or `""`. An object evaluates always to `true`. (You can check it in the JS console in your browser by typing `!!{}`).

Either you should remove the whole condition or the '!'.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an object just do this:

`delete object.node;`

**ATTENTION**

For objects you can't use `object.length` it won't return anything, you must use `Object.getLength(object);`

Comment: if(object.hasOwnProperty(node)){ delete object.node }